# For-comprehension for two arrays of the same length

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have two `Seq[Array[Byte]]` arrays:

```
var o1: Seq[Array[Byte]]
var o2: Seq[Array[Byte]]
//...
```

I need to ***mutate*** the `o1` Seq of Arrays  so that each array of `o1` is replaced with Array of `o2` of the same position ***iff*** the array of `o2` has non-zero length.

Is it possible to do with for-comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a better job for `zip`

```
o1 zip o2 map { case (l, r) => if(r.nonEmpty) r else l }
```

If you don't like creating the intermediate seq with `o1 zip o2`, you could lazily build up the combination using iterators:

```
(o1.iterator zip o2.iterator map { case (l, r) => if(r.nonEmpty) r else l }).toList
```

---

If you *really* want to mutate, first make sure to use a [`collection.mutable.IndexedSeq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/IndexedSeq.html) since its mutation method (`update`) takes an index. If you try to mutate a general `Seq`, you might get O(n) updates due to linked list-ish structures.

```
for {
  (replacement, index) <- o2.iterator.zipWithIndex
  if replacement.nonEmpty
} o1(index) = replacement
```

This is actually just syntax sugar for something like:

```
o2.iterator.zipWithIndex.foreach {
  case (replacement, index) =>
    if(replacement.nonEmpty) o1.update(index, replacement)
}
```